# Nginx maintenance page exclude certain IP

Tags: nginx

```
location / {

#               if($remote_addr != 99.99.99.99){
                        return 503;
#               }
}
```

current 503 page works fine, but if I try to add IP exclusion like above

on nginx restart I get following error

```
 nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "if($remote_addr" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite:74
```

all online guide points to use $remote_addr as above, is there any reason mine won't work?

UPDATED

currently this shows maintenance to all visitors including the 99 (yes I replaced it with my real IP).

```
map $remote_addr $condition {
        default 1;
        99.99.99.99 0;
}
Server{
        location / {
                if ($condition) {
                        return 503;
                }
        }
}
```

also using remote_host I get nginx unknown "remote_host" variable,

still not able to get it to exclude my IP from 503

Comment: You are missing the space between `if` and `(`

Comment: Yes, actually that one I figured out, but why would updated code not work (that has space)

Answer (score 2):

I used [nginx map module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) for periodically maintenance exception.

For example:

1. map $remote_host to $maint_except

```
map $remote_host $maint_switch {
    default       1;
```

```
99.99.99.99   0;
```

}

2. Check $maint_switch instead of $remote_addr

`location / {
     if ($maint_switch) {
                        return 503;
     }
}`

Comment: not familiar with nginx syntax, does `if (!$maint_switch)` work?

Comment: `!$maint_switch` will be work. if it does not work, `!=` operator or change mapping values will work.

Comment: tried your code, /usr/sbin/nginx -t syntax check went okay, but the site shows maintenance page for all, see my updated first post